# Is this moka still safe to use?

Tags: moka

My Bialetti Moka has porous holes that seem to go beneath the surface. These pictures show those small holes.

[image]
(click to enlarge)

Comment: Can you elaborate why you think it might not be safe? Are you concerned about the integirty of the device (catastrophic failure during brewing) or with the apparent disappearance of metal (and the possibility that you have ingested it)? Also, is your pot made of steel or aluminum?

Answer (score 1):

Safe or not, I think it comes with the territory.  I've had mine (2 actually) for 5+ years now and it is quite pitted, itself.  I think this is naturally what happens when (mineral) water boils against metals.  I don't know how relevant it is, but I tend to get right to enjoying my coffee, and neglect the moka. Coffee (acidic) seeps down into the reservoir, and I suspect that might contribute to the pitting.  I have no doubt that I've drunk this metal, but thankfully being a food product it is a safe metal; they don't make these things out of lead, you know.  I'm no chemist, biologist or doctor, but I have had a fair amount of experience with a couple of mokas and friends who also use them, and they all inevitably pit.  I don't know if it's safe, but it seems to be the norm, and I have yet to hear of any recalls. Bialetti is a reputable company. And the FDA (or whoever) wouldnt approve a food product that was dangerous.